# How to access bloodhound from a Twitter Typeahead object?

Tags: twitter-typeahead

I am initializing Twitter Typeahead in the normal way, i.e.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  minLength: 3,
  highlight: true
},
{
  name: 'my-dataset',
  source: mySource
});
```

`mySource` is a Bloodhound instance and I want to access it from the already initialsed Typeahead.  How do I do that?  (I want to call bloodhound.clear() - I'm hoping that it will clear the results which are being cached on an ajax call).

I tried `$('.typeahead').source`, and `$('.typeahead').typeahead().source`, and other combinations, but no luck.

Comment: The source is instantiated and configured in another function that I do not have access to.